# buefy b-table doesn't automatically move to next page when the :per-page value is exceeded?

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I have used the b-table component with the :per-page attribute set to 10.The issue here is when i add the 11th row to the table, the row gets added but the current page is still the first page.

```
 <b-button @click="addTableRow('compensationData', 'compensationData','compensationAmt')" class="is-radiusless">Add Effective Date</b-button>
    <b-table
      ref="compensationData"
      :data="this.objectData.compensationData"
      :hoverable="true"
      :paginated="true"
      :per-page="10"
      selectable
      @select="selected"
      detailed
      icon-pack="mdi"
      width="60%"
    
    >
```

How to automatically move to the next page when the number of pages added are more than 10 in the current page? Please help?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to change page when a new row is added.

But you can check for the number of rows and set current page accordingly.

```js
    // template
    b-table(
        :current-page.sync="currentPage"
        :per-page="perPage"
    )

    // script
    data() {
        currentPage: 1,
        perPage: 10
    },
    methods: {
        whenNewRowIsAdded() {
            this.currentPage = Math.ceil(this.objectData.compensationData.length / this.perPage)
        }
    }
```